# Can you un-build a production build of create-react-app to get the source code?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My laptop got stolen and I made a fatal error of not pushing my changes to Github, thereby losing close to 2 weeks worth of work. This was a [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build) project.

Luckily, I had pushed the most recent production build to my server, so I have the compilied/minified version of my project that comes from running `npm run build`

Is there a way to un-build my react project to its original source code?

> I feel very dumb for not pushing my code to Github sooner, and have learned a valuable lesson in frequent commits.

Comment: Chunks include a source map. You can check in the Sources tab of developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

**Just delete your build folder**

You can delete your build folder and it works fine it doesn't effect `public` or `src` folders. So delete and keep going.

If you need to build again just repeat the process of building.

Answer (score -1):

I'm so sorry, I'm afraid you can't.